# Improve performance and speed in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, performance

Recently switching from Classic to Lightining and users started feeling very slow to load the page, does anybody has any pointers what might the case and what to look for in order to make it faster and improve the performance of Salesforce organization for Lightning Users.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the speed of lightning as compared to classic is just part of the package unfortunately. One thing to keep in mind is lightning has very aggressive caching policies, so it's likely that over a short period of time - your common tasks & pages seem faster.

That being said. Some things to recommend / keep in mind are

- Reducing Fields: When setting up Lightning, users often have some 100-200 fields on the page, and this can lead to slow load speeds.
- Related Lists: Active related lists can get bulky, so another way to speed things up is by minimizing the number of these on the page.
- Disable unnecessary Plug-ins: Depending on the CPU power/memory resources, your plug-ins and extensions use, you may have to disable some of them.

> Salesforce Lightning at Lightning Speeds (Tips for Improving Load Speed) https://www.xtivia.com/salesforce-lightning-at-lightning-speeds/